# Custom xib cells are not appearing on UITableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

my cells are not appearing.
I did:

- Checked if datasource and delegate were connected
- Checked if my custom cells identifier name and class were correct

Things that I didn't:
I am struggling with auto layout, so I just decided not to do it.

My app is loading with the correct amount of cells, but the cells are not registered.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UITableViewController, NetworkManagerDelegate {

    private var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    private var infoForCells = [Result]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ImageViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "imageCell")
        
        networkManager.delegate = self
        networkManager.fetchNews()
        
        
        
        
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return infoForCells.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
         guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageViewCell else{
            return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }

        
        let cellIndex = infoForCells[indexPath.row]

        
        cell.titleForImage.text = cellIndex.alt_description
        print(cell.titleForImage ?? "lol")
//        if let image = cellIndex.urlToImage {
//            cell.imageForArticle.load(url: image)
//        }
        
        return cell
        
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
    
    func didUpdateNews(root: Root) {
        infoForCells = root.results

     
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload the table

```
func didUpdateNews(root: Root) {
  infoForCells = root.results
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Sh_Khan** answer you can also listen to updates of `infoForCells` property

```swift
private var infoForCells = [Result]() {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
             self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to listen to the property? I mean for what purpose can I use "didSet"?

Comment: It's will automatically update your table view every time you change infoForCells value, just convenience